# Deployement Nuxt.js ssr on passenger : SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js, passenger

I'm deploying my nuxt app on planethoster who use Passenger to run Node.js Application. I build the app by using ">npm run build" and deployed the content off .nuxt folder on the server, with "server.js" as entrypoint. but I ran on the following error:

```
/home/scalcmjx/test.scalomhouseplans.com/server.js:1
import Vue from 'vue'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at Module.require (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at loadApplication (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:243:2)
    at setupEnvironment (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:214:2)
```

Please Someone know how to manage it?

Answer (score 0):

What is your node.js version? Try using the [current LTS](https://nodejs.dev/): `14.17.0`
If I'm not mistaken, the `import` syntax is officially supported since v14, so this should maybe fix one issue.

Also, you need to deploy dist and not .nuxt, the latter is used for caching purposes.

I'm not sure of what is the process for this specific host, but you should probably get some decent ideas from the deployment section of the official documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/deploying-to-21yunbox

There are a lot of hosting solutions there, one is probably looking like Planethoster.